# Why does a generic type that can be casted not get implicitly converted?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I have a class `A` and a class `B`, both generic with a type parameter `T`. An object of `A<T>` can be casted to `B<T>`. I have a generic operator overload on `B` that I want to be able to call on an `A` object and a `B` object, where the `A` object gets implicitly converted.

When I try this it does not compile:

```
template <typename T>
class A {};

template <typename T>
class B {
public:
    B() {}
    B(const A<T> &a) {}
};

template <typename T>
B<T> operator*(const B<T> &obj1, const B<T> &obj2) {
    return B<T>(); // doesn't matter
}

int main() {
    A<int> objA;
    B<int> objB;

    B<int> combined1 = objA * objB; // error: operator* isn't defined on these types
    B<int> combined2 = static_cast<B<int>>(objA) * objB; // fine

    return 0;
}
```

However when A and B aren't generic, it works fine:

```
class A {};

class B {
public:
    B() {}
    B(const A &a) {}
};

B operator*(const B &obj1, const B &obj2) {
    return B(); // doesn't matter
}

int main() {
    A objA;
    B objB;

    B combined1 = objA * objB; // fine
    B combined2 = static_cast<B>(objA) * objB; // also fine

    return 0;
}
```

Why is this? Is there something about making the operator overload generic that means the type can't be inferred?

Comment: There are no "generic" classes in C++, and none of  `A`, `B`, `A<T>` and `B<T>` are types.

Comment: Yeah my terminology is probably off but I hope the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, implicit conversions are not allowed while doing argument deduction, I can think of a *derived to base* as one that is allowed. The expression

```
B<int> combined1 =  objA * objB;
```

expect to find viable overloads for `objA * objB`, including those found by ADL, one possible is:

```
template <typename T>
B<T> operator*(const A<T> &obj1, const B<T> &obj2) {...}
```

but none is found, the overload you provide is not a candidate, hence the call fail, but if you provide the explicit template argument to the operator, then there will be nothing to deduce and the implicit conversion through the converting constructor will allow the call:

```
 B<int> combined1 = operator*<int>(objA, objB);
```

But I would not do that, stick with the cast it better explain the intent.

Comment: Yeah being explicit is probably better, I was just wondering why it can't be done with templates but I guess it makes sense that implicit conversions aren't possible while deducing arguments.

Comment: The way to select overload is not that: we don't expect that overload. We considers overload (ADL, ...), filter viable overloads (here, OP's overload is discarded), then select the best one if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can define friend function in `class A` which call your template function

```
template <class T>
class B;

template <typename T>
class A {
    friend B<T> operator*(const B<T> &obj1, const B<T> &obj2) {} # here call template function
};

template <typename T>
class B {
public:
    B() {}
    B(const A<T> &a) {}

};

template <typename T>
B<T> operator*(const B<T> &obj1, const B<T> &obj2) {
    return B<T>(); // doesn't matter
}

int main() {
    A<int> objA;
    B<int> objB;

    B<int> combined1 = objA * objB; // fine
    B<int> combined2 = static_cast<B<int>>(objA) * objB; // fine

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `operator*` "belongs" to `B`, not `A`. And template `operator*` should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

During argument deduction, conversion/promotion doesn't occurs, so for

```
objA * objB
```

When checking validity of candidates overload, `T` cannot be deduced for:

```
template <typename T> B<T> operator*(const B<T> &, const B<T> &);
```

So that overload is rejected.

One way to fix that is to create a non template function. Asit should apply to classe template, one way to do it is with `friend` functions:

```
template <typename T>
class B {
public:
    B() {}
    B(const A<T>&) {}

    friend B operator*(const B&, const B&) { return /*...*/; }
};
```

Now, `objA * objB` considers overload `B<int> operator*(const B<int>&, const B<int>&)` and conversion can occurs to see if function is viable (and it is).

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6790c9dd029b809)